# docker .. exec: "--platform=linux/arm64": stat --platform=linux/arm64: no such file or directory: unknown

Tags: linux, docker, macos, apple-m1

After a weekend running docker start failing

```bash
docker run -it -p 9095:9095 tp-service-java-arm64 --platform=linux/arm64
```

> docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "--platform=linux/arm64": stat --platform=linux/arm64: no such file or directory: unknown.

This is mac with M1 CPU

Comment: Anything after the `docker run image-name` is interpreted as the main command to run in the container.  Do you need to move that option before the image name, or do you expect the main container process to understand it?  If the latter, can you [edit] the question to include the Dockerfile and any other necessary source code?

Comment: Please include the Dockerfile as we would need to see how it is built, what you passed to EXEC, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, running now as

```
docker run -it --platform=linux/arm64 -p 9095:9095 tp-service-java-arm64
```

I have to build special image for arm64
and run it this way, as alternative Intel/amd64 fails to run on M1 mac.